# Start activity without showing it

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A, which starts activity B and activity B starts activity C. Is there a way not to show activity B.
I want this behavour because if there is no content (eg for ListView) for activity B, show activity C on which I select some data, and then press back button to go back to activity B.
The point is that I would like to have activity B on activity stack, but not to show it in certain cases.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution:

- Activity A starts activity B with extra parameter (intent.putExtra("something", true))
- Activity B:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("something") && getIntent().getBooleanExtra("something", false) {
            //show activity B
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_B);
    } else {
            //don't show activity B, start activity C
        startActivityForResult(activity_C, ACTIVITY_NOT_INITIALIZED); //start activity C
    }
}
```

//when came back from activity C, check if activity B was already initialized

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_NOT_INITIALIZED) {
        //show activity B
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_B);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In your manifest set

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

for your activity.

Comment: also you need extend `Activity` not `AppCompactActivity`

Comment: With `extends Activity` I'm getting this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {myActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity {myActivity} did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing

Comment: This is the correct answer, and you can still extend `AppCompatActivity` (from androidx at least).  All the other answers still showed a brief flash of the Activity before it launched the new one.

Answer (score 3):

do not set setContentView() for activity B

Comment: Then returning to this activity will be with problems :)

Comment: It's true, but you will see the blank page for half a second before activity C starts. I don't want this.
Returning is not a problem because you can handle it in onResume().

Answer (score 1):

just call `startActivity()` in `onCreate()` method of activity B. It will not be shown, but it will be in activity stack.

Comment: It's true, but you will see the blank page for half a second before activity C starts. I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call startActivity, without calling setContentView for a layout. Hope this helps!

Comment: Then returning to this activity will be with problems :)