# Using activitygroups, how to switch to a deeper activity within a different tabhost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, flags, activitygroup

If I was to rewrite this again, I would use fragments but instead im using the following setup:

- Activites in the Tabhost are managed by ActivityGroups
- I've TabA, TabB and TabC
- By default, the main activity is TabB so this is the landing page
- When TabB starts, it looks at sharedpreference to see if a variable is set
- If the variable is set then the user sees the main landing screen
- If the variable is not set, its routed to a sub activity under TabC i.e. TabC -> Activity2-- - There are two Activities under TabC, Activity 1 -> Activity2

My issue is how to show Activity2 within tabhost TabC but with where TabC is highlighted and the user is not shown Activity1 until they select the back button from Activity2.

This is probably a simple answer but I think I've been looking at the code too long!

Thanks for help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

i am not really sure what you want. May b this answer will help you. try to call your activity1 in oncreate method of activity2 and finish() activity2. if you want to switch from activity2 to activity1

Comment: I found this possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571887/start-activity-without-showing-it which would allow me to call setCurretTab that would change the tabhost, passing in some param I can then call activity2 and when the user selects the back button I would then init activity1.

Comment: Not having much luck with this issue! I can see a lot of tutorials on how to move between activities with a tabhost but not to invoke an activity within another tabhost.