# Android Start Activity Using Only onCreate

Tags: android, view, android-activity, stack

I have a feature on my app that is:

I can open a specific activity by clicking to open files with extension ".sso".
But when I open the app I have to travel till a specific activity, and for that I travel 3 activities, creating them.. But I can see them being created with the layout.
I just want to place them at the stack.
I tryed to use setContentView only at onStart method, but still it shows... I only want to run onCreate method of the 3 activities dont want the method onStart.

Possible?
Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571887/start-activity-without-showing-it

Comment: Thanks Torben I had already found that , but thanks ;)